# Flutter, How to handle the scroll of PDF Viewer when the parent has a long height with scroll?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I have a `column` include several widgets. This `column` is the parent and **its children cause the `column` has scroll**. On the other hand I used [PDF View Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_plugin) and its `PdfVeiwer` widget inside the `column`.

But I have a problem. **If both of the `PdfVeiwer` and the `Column` widgets have scroll.** I can not scroll the PDF pages and just the `Column` can scroll!

How should I solve this problem?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ExpandablePanel(
        hasIcon: false,
        header: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              Text('Title'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        expanded: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 500.0,
              child: PdfViewer(filePath: path),   
            )),
      ),

      //My Other widgets are here 

    ],
  ),
);
```